# How to include a PHP Class file from the above folder

Tags: php

I am trying to include the File from the above folder . Iam here (www/pf/htdocs/ap) . 
I want to include a php file from  the above www it is dev/libraray/hp.php

i am doing it in this way `include_once ('../../../../dev/libraray/hp.php')` but could not do it How could i do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Be sure that target path is readable by PHP interpreter (can be read by user running it).
2. If so, play with the "../" path, adding or substracting it from the `include()` string. for this one, removing it once should fix the problem, because you need to go 3 levels down:

`include_once ('../../../dev/libraray/hp.php')`

Answer (score 0):

Use the actual server directory path.

ex. include('/home/username/include.php');

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in case you change the locations and folders or define a base path like `define('BASE_URL', dirname($_SERVER["file_name"]));`